# Newly added post takes the likes and comment counts of previous post in vue.js/laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm currently learning vue.js. However, i'm having a hard time trying to debug an error on a project i'm current doing, a blog-like app, with Laravel as the back-end.
In my home blade.file, I have a root component called `<timeline>` where i have the textarea to add a post and then a component called `<posts>`. Inside `<posts>` , i have `<post>` component where individual post details are shown.
I also have a component `<feedback>` for likes and comment counts, all of which worked perfectly.
However, my challenge is that each time i add a new post, the new post instead of having likes count and comment count of 0 inherits the feedback
of the previous post.(Say the previous post had 10 likes and 5 comments, once i enter a new post, it instantly shows likes of 10 and comment count of 5 instead of 0 since its new post and has none yet). The previous post in turn takes the feedback of the one before it and so on. 
How do i correct this error please?
My components are as shown below:

```
//Timeline component
<template>
    <div class="timeline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="body" class="form-control" v-model="postText" rows="4" placeholder="What's on your mind"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="sendPost">Post</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <posts :posts="posts"></posts>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                postText: '',
                posts: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            loadPost(){
                axios.get('/post').then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.posts = response.data;
                })
            },
            sendPost(){
                if(!this.postText || this.postText.trim() === ''){
                return;
             }

             //send to db
             axios.post('/post', {
                body: this.postText.trim()
             }).then(response=> {
                console.log(response);
                this.loadPost();
             });
             this.postText = '';
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.loadPost();
        }
    }
</script>

//posts component
<template>
    <div class="posts">
        <div v-for="post in posts">
            <post :post="post"></post>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['posts']
    }
</script>
```

Here is my post component

```
<template>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                <img :src="'/images/profile_pix/avatar.png'" class="media-object center-block" alt="#"/>
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h5><strong> {{ post.user.username }}</strong></h5>
                <small>{{ post.created_at }}</small>
                  <p>{{ post.body }} </p>
                <feedback :post="post"></feedback>
            </div>
        </div><hr>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['post']
    }
</script>
```

and here is my feedback component

```
<template>
    <div class="feedback">
        <span v-if="liked"><a href="#" @click.prevent="unLikeApost"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>Unlike</a></span>
        <span v-else="liked"><a href="#" @click.prevent="likeApost"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Like</a></span>
        <span><small> {{likes}} </small></span>                        
        <span>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></a>&nbsp <small> {{ comments }} </small>
        </span>
        <span v-if="author">
          <a href="#" v-if="author" class="pull-right"><small>Delete</small></a>
        </span> 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      props: ['post'],
      data(){
        return {
          author: false,
          likes: '',
          liked: false,
          comments: ''
        } 
      },
      methods: {
        getLikes(){
          axios.get('/likes/'+this.post.id+'/getlikes').then((response) => {
            if(response.data === 0){
              this.likes = 0;
            }
            this.likes = response.data;
          })
        },
        checkIfLiked(){
          axios.get('/likes/'+ this.post.id +'/checkliked').then((response) => {
            if(response.data === 1){
              this.liked = true;
            }
          })
        },
        likeApost(){
            axios.post('/likes/'+ this.post.id +'/likeapost').then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data);
              this.likes += 1;
              this.liked = true;
            })
        },
        unLikeApost(){
            axios.post('/likes/'+ this.post.id +'/unlikeapost').then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data);
              this.likes -= 1;
              this.liked = false;
            })
        },
        countComments(){
          axios.get('/post/'+ this.post.id +'/countcomments').then((response) => {
            this.comments = response.data;
          })
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        // determine author
        axios.get('/post/' +this.post.id+'/getposter').then((response) => {
          let auth_user = window.Laravel.user.id;
          let author = response.data;
          if (auth_user === author){
            this.author = true;
          }
        });

        this.getLikes();

        this.checkIfLiked();

        this.countComments();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Since you're passing the post into `feedback` as a prop, it might be that the api is returning the wrong post. It sounds a lot like an array counting issue. Is there something in the backend code that's returning the incorrect post or are you sure the correct data is reaching the front end?

Comment: Thanks @tom_h. It looks to me that the correct posts are been returned from the backend. When I add a new post, it's stored in the database and the posts are fetched from the database and displayed. However, the new post is expected to have zero likes and comments, here it does not.The likes and comment counts of the previous post is displayed under the new post instead. However, when I refresh the page, it displays zero likes and comments as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little strange to me that you're issuing GET /post after submitting the new post instead of GET /post/:id.  Or just adding the created response onto your're existing array.

/edit Disregard the above, I see you're just re-running the method that gets all the posts.  The singular post is confusing there, maybe that ought to be /posts :)

The issue may be related to the [key on v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key), try using the id of your posts there.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. I just replaced  :post="post" in my component with :key=post.id but the behaviour remains the same. Please note that once I refresh the page the correct counts are fetched and rendered as 0. This error shows up immediately I post an entry and it's displayed. What could I be doing wrong?